# Very slow database connection open for MSDASQL provider on IIS Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic, iis-express, adodb

I have found when using the MSDASQL provider in classic asp on IIS Express that opening the ADODB database connection is slow (between 2 and 8 seconds).

Also it seems to queue other things up, as in the IIS trace I'm also seeing that sometimes the event ASP_DEQUEUE_REQUEST can take 8 seconds.

I have just found a workaround in the surface area configuration to allow remote connections to the database server it works fine.

However I don't particularly want to enable remote connections, so I'm wondering if anyone knows that background to this problem. I have done extensive research and not found anything yet.

I've tried alternative providers and using ".", localhost etc etc.

Any ideas?

I'm thinking perhaps it's something to do with connection pooling? But I don't have any settings defined for this, so I'm assuming it's using the defaults.

-thanks
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

MSDASQL has been depricated.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx) explains the alternatives.

Comment: Very useful resource thanks @Diodeus.Though (perhaps I've missed something) MSDASQL is listed under the "Current MDAC/WDAC Components", rather than deprecated ones. Is it because MSDASQL in classic asp is using something deprecated underneath? If so, do you know which one? (I'm guessing it's SQLOLEDB?)

Comment: That is correct Alex, MSDASQL is the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC, that one is NOT deprecated, on the other hand, SQL Server Native Client provider will be deprecated (SQLNCLI)